# Solid Principles in OSGI

Tags: java, oop, osgi, solid-principles

I was reading this article:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/solid-principles-modularity

and the author states that the most important place to use the SOLID principles is at the module joints, "It is these joints within the system that require the greatest flexibility and resiliency. The reason for this is driven by change. Change that is encapsulated within a single module poses less threat than change that ripples across many modules.".

Because OSGI can be used to define these joints, I decided to look at OSGI to see how it uses the SOLID principles.

Single Responsibility is an easy one, a module/bundle/jar should do one thing only. Dependency Inversion Principle seems clear to me, a implementation in a module/bundle/jar should not depend on another implementation but on an abstraction. And the modules should not expose any implementation details. OSGI does this by creating a component model that publish or reference services.

But what about the other principles? For example Liskov substitution principle or the interface segregation principle, where can I find examples of these in OSGI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module needs to conform to its published interface (Liskov Substitution) which is its only entry point (interface segregation).

Comment: Exactly. The "respect its published interface" is a bit messy, because interfaces as it stands cannot check the contract, only abstract classes can do this.

Comment: Let me try to flesh out what you are saying. BundleActivator has a published interface and uses Template Method DP. One or more steps can be overridden by subclasses to allow differing behaviors while ensuring that the specific behavior is still followed. Furthermore BundleActivator behavior could be verified with pre and post conditions. After start a bundle should be in start state, after stop a bundle should be in stop state. BundleActivator also conform to interface segregation because implementors do not need to implement methods they do not use, every module needs to start and stop.